# Border colors of my chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I made an example chart with [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com).
The problem are the different colors of the borders. When you look closely, you will see, that the left and bottom borders are black, whereas the top and right border are gray:

[image]

Is there any way to control the border color? I want them all to be grey.

This is the code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "autoMarginOffset": 20,
  "dataProvider": data,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
  }, {
    "position": "left",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
  }, {
    "id": "v3",
    "position": "right",
    "axisAlpha": 0
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "xField": "ax",
    "yField": "ay",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "xField": "bx",
    "yField": "by",
    "yAxis": "v3",
  }]
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyy8h0xo/).

Answer (score 0):

The lines are already grey (technically black with a gridAlpha of 0.15 by default), however the overlap of the grid lines at zero from multiple axes causes those axis lines on the left and bottom to look darker.

You have to set [`zeroGridAlpha`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#zeroGridAlpha) to 0 in all of your axes to make the lines at the left and bottom look more like the other sides of the chart:

```
  "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "zeroGridAlpha": 0
  }, {
    "position": "left",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "zeroGridAlpha": 0
  }, {
    "id": "v3",
    "position": "right",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "zeroGridAlpha": 0
  }],
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyy8h0xo/1/)